# Constructor Formatting c# - PadLeft Property of Class

Tags: c#, class, constructor, format, padleft

Is there a better way to do what is done in the code that follows?  I added a PadLeft in the constructor because I need the leading zero and 10 characters.  The leading zero is stripped off, for some reason, in my call to the API that returns the "wbd10" value.  I did this the old way, but was just wondering if there is a better way to do this?

```
public class wqpWBD10
{
    string _wbd10;

    public string WBD10 
    {
        get { return _wbd10; }
        set { _wbd10 = value.PadLeft(10, '0'); }
    }
    public string WBD10Name { get; set; }
    public string HUC8 { get; set; }
    public string HUC8Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please align your title to sample code: there is no constructor at all... Also consider simplifying sample to `value.PadLeft(10,'0')` and stating what value you pass in and what result you get/expect.

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine. If `value = 1234`, you'll set `0000001234` to your local variable.

You may want to check that `value` is not `null`, or the call to `PadLeft` will throw an exception.

```
public string WBD10 
{
    get { return _wbd10; }
    set
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            _wbd10 = value.PadLeft(10, '0');

        // If value is null, take some other action (or do nothing)
    }
}
```

Also, you're dealing with a property setter. The constructor *(which I don't see here)* would be:

```
public wqpWBD10()
{
}
```